# Inserting X in its correct position in a sorted list

Tags: prolog

In prolog how do I insert X in its correct position in a sorted list?

My Attempt:

```
insert(X,[Y|Rest],[X,Y|Rest]):-
X @< Y;
insert(X,Rest,BiggerRest).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you need to make this three cases.

```
insert(X, [], [X]).
insert(X, [Y|Rest], [X,Y|Rest]) :-
    X @< Y, !.
insert(X, [Y|Rest0], [Y|Rest]) :-
    insert(X, Rest0, Rest).
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Is it possible to do the same procedure using the built in predicate setof?

Comment: @General_9: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Isn't the built in predicate setof essentially builds up an ordered list of items that do not include duplicates. Is there any way to piggyback of that functionality when trying to insert one element into an ordered list?

Comment: @General_9: I guess you could just do `sort([X|Xs], Sorted)` to insert `X` in the right place. That would take O(n lg n) time though, while the above takes O(n).