# insert function in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am working on writing an insert function that takes two arguments, a number and a sorted list and it should produce that same list with the number included in its proper position. 
Here's what I got so far:

```
insert1(X,[]) :-
   [X].

insert1(X, [H|T]) :-
   X > H,
   insert1(X,T).

insert1(X,[H|_T]) :-
   X < H,
   T is [X|T].
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: '.'/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated ("x" must hold one character)
Exception: (6) insert1(2, [1, 4, 5]) ? creep
```

I would appreciate your help folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message it's rather cryptic: '.'/2 it's the list constructor, and you're *calling* it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022779/prolog-unusual-cons-syntax-for-lists/10023905#10023905) question for a detailed explanation of the syntax.

Also the last clause is wrong, because is/2 *must* be used only for arithmetic.

But generally you are approaching the problem from a wrong 'perspective'. Arguments in Prolog are *immutable*. You need another argument to hold the modified list.

Here is a possible workaround for the first and third clause

```
insert1(X, [], [X]).
...
insert1(X, [H|T], [X,H|T]) :-
  X < H.
```

You will need to adjust the second clause and invoke insert1 in this way

```
?- insert1(3, [1,2,3,4], L).
```

Comment: CapelliC, let me work on this and I will get back to you if i have any problems. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am still having issues with this one: Here's what I have so far:  insert1(X,[],[X]).
 insert1(X,[H|T],[H|T]) :-
     X > H,
     insert1(X,T,_T1).
 insert1(X,[H|_T],[X,H|T]) :-
     X < H.  I am getting the same original list if I try to insert something in my list. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: second rule must copy H, but T will change, then introduce another Var and pass it down into recursive call.

Comment: This is what I have to the best of my understanding about the hint you gave sir:  insert1(X,[],[X]).
 insert1(X,[H|T],[H|T1]) :-
     X > H,
     insert1(X,T,[_Z|T1]).
 insert1(X,[H|_T],[X,H|_T1]) :-
     X < H.

Comment: Why do you prefix variables with underscore? don't ! Attempt to keep rules simple as possible. Second rule will be *very* similar to third I wrote in the answer!

Comment: thanks for the help so far. When you say introduce new Var, how do I use that var ?

Comment: This is what I got so far and strangely I tested for 3 [4,5] it works but if do 3 [2,4,5], it displays [2,4,5]..Any ideas why? Here's my code: insert1(X,[],[X]).
insert1(X,[H|T],[X,H|T]) :-
     X < H.
  
insert1(X,[H|T],[H|T]) :-
     X > H,
     insert1(X,T,_T1).

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004265/inserting-x-in-its-correct-position-in-a-sorted-list

Comment: Again in your third rule you have _T1, that's a singleton! Well, the rule should read `insert1(X,[H|T],[H|R]) :- X > H, insert1(X,T,R).`